# Firebase observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue extremely slow

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently developing an iOS app with a Firebase realtime database connected to it.

I'm new to Firebase, but following the tutorials on Firebase gives me some extremely slow queries.

I have tried to separate the query to a ViewController with no other activities just to make sure that nothing else was obstructing the query to load.

In my `viewDidLoad()` I have the following request to the node 'vibes' of my Firebase Realtime Database:

```
[[self.ref child:@"vibes"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.exists) {
    //do stuff with the returned snapshot...
    }

}];
```

The query should in my opinion load quite quickly as the snapshot returned is the following:

```
Printing description of snapshot:
Snap (vibes) {
"-KeILdmnrDSk_EQvlkoD" =     {
    CreationTime = "2017030003 09:47:41+0100";
    GroupIDs =         {
        "-KdVgP47A5BBr4Nfbg7W" = 1;
    };
    Length = 6;
    LocationLatitude = "55.69795108489616";
    LocationLongitude = "12.51176020166862";
    ResponseToStory = 3;
    StoryType = 0;
    TaggePeopleIDs =         {
        V2udnQjZN1RCL2zaInWMM4wBKFE3 = 1;
        WJpOvZVGo1UMEoLTk8l9ulKF9Ju2 = 1;
        m0gjQQS0WRcArjNs9rEFLEi7bz63 = 1;
        sK6XSwQhEOOPD2HjAQ6hWFG4GIo2 = 1;
    };
    TaggedEvent = "Vibes Development";
    TaggedPeople =         {
        0 =             {
            FriendID = m0gjQQS0WRcArjNs9rEFLEi7bz63;
            ProfilePicURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...";
            friendsscore = 0;
            name = "Best friend";
        };
    };
    TaggedPlace = CSE;
    VibeID = "-KeILdmnrDSk_EQvlkoD";
    VibeImageURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...";
    VibeRating = 0;
    VibeSetting = 0;
    };
}
```

But it turns out to take approximately 20-30 seconds every time I try. (Setting a break point on the first line and wait until the app enters a breakpoint inside the block).

It's the same no matter which node in my database I try to retrieve (no matter how much data I want to load).

Additional info: I'm currently on a WiFi-connection with ~120Mbps download speed

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue too, have you found any solution?